# TensorFlow String Input Producer Size()

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to do a sanity check on the size of the queue created by `tf.train.string_input_producer` (r1.3) but just get zero size when expected to get size of three

```py
import tensorflow as tf

file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv'])

print('type(file_queue): {}'.format(type(file_queue)))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    file_queue_size = sess.run(file_queue.size())

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

print('result of queue size operation: {}'.format(file_queue_size))
```

My hunch was that there was some sort of lazy initialization going on so I figured I would ask the queue for an item and see what the size was after

```py
import tensorflow as tf

file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv'])

print('type(file_queue): {}'.format(type(file_queue)))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    item = sess.run(file_queue.dequeue())
    file_queue_size = sess.run(file_queue.size())

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

print('result of queue size operation: {}'.format(file_queue_size))
```

While the size is no longer zero, the size provided is not two and changes every time the code is run.

I feel like getting the size is a simple thing but maybe this is just not the way to interact with `data_flow_ops.FIFOQueue`.  Any insight to explain what is going on here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an artifact of the async nature in which queues are filled up by the queue runners. Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['file1.csv','file2.csv','file3.csv'])

print('type(file_queue): {}'.format(type(file_queue)))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    time.sleep(1)
    file_queue_size = sess.run(file_queue.size())

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)

print('result of queue size operation: {}'.format(file_queue_size))
```

The output should say `result of queue size operation: 32`. By pausing the main thread, the queue runners could run for long enough to fill up the queue.
Why `32` and not `3`? Let's look at the signature for `string_input_producer`:

```
string_input_producer(
    string_tensor,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    capacity=32,
    shared_name=None,
    name=None,
    cancel_op=None
)
```

Two main things to note here:

1. `num_epochs=None` means keep iterating on the list of items forever. To iterate over the list just once set `num_epochs=1`. You will also need to call `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())`. With `num_epochs=1` if you run the size op after dequeues you will see the size reducing.
2. `capacity=32` this is the default capacity of the queue. Which is why we are seeing `32` instead of `3` in the output above.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful and would be great addition to the TF docs.